# Get Controller and Action name in your view template?

Tags: laravel

I wonder if how i can get the Controller name and Action name in the Blade template/View?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options.

Pass variables to the view from your controller.
Set a global view variable
use view composer.
You need to choose one of these depending on your use case.

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction();
Route::currentRouteAction();
Route::currentRouteName();
```